# Menu selection with if else and switch

Tags: java, eclipse, if-statement, switch-statement

Hi I am programming a calculator with the 5 choices of operations.

```
1. Addition
2. Subtraction
3. Multiplication
4. Division
5. Exit
```

I want to ask the user to make a choice of the operation and check whether the choice valid (i.e. 1 - 5) If not, give a wrong message and prompt the user to select again.

I am thinking using if-else statement with switch statement within the else statement.

```
System.out.printf("What would you like to do? ");
int selection = input.nextInt();

if  (selection!=1 || 2 || 3 || 4 || 5) {  

    System.out.println("You have entered an invalid choice, please re-enter      
    your choice: ");
}/*end if    as long as the selection is NOT a 1 - 5, prompt the user to 
 re-enter*/

else {
    switch(selection){

        case 1:
        case 2:
        case 3:
        case 4:
        case 5;
```

I am getting an Eclipse compiler  error at the `if` line: 
`The operator || is undefined for the argument type(s) boolean, int`

Any ideas what is wrong and how to fix this? Thanks

Kelvin

Answer (score 1):

You don't even need that `if` statement

```
switch(selection){
    case 1:
    // handle 1
        break;
    case 2:
    // handle 2
        break;
    case 3:
    // handle 3
        break;
    case 4:
    // handle 4
        break;
    case 5:
    // handle 5
        break;
    default:
        System.out.println("You have entered an invalid choice, please re-enter      
your choice: ");
        break;
}
```

The `default` clause will handle every statement that doesn't fit in any of the cases.

Answer (score 0):

The `if` statement needs valid expressions between the conditional operators. Perhaps

```
if (selection != 1 && selection != 2 && selection != 3
        && selection != 4 && selection != 5) {
   ...    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot combine conditional cases like that in Java like we would in English.  "If the selection is not 1 or 2 or 3 or 4 or 5" cannot be translated to Java that way.  You must explicitly state `selection` each time, or else the compiler will think you are attempting to use the `||` operator on `selection != 1`, a `boolean`, and `2`, an `int`, hence the error.  Additionally, the value is always "not 1" *or* "not 2" *or* ...   You should use "and" (`&&`).

```
if (selection!=1 && selection!=2 && selection!=3 && selection!=4 && selection!=5) {
```

This can be simplified because the numbers are consecutive:

```
if (selection < 1 || selection > 5)
```